# Fill grid with colors following pattern rules

Tags: logic, constraint-programming, minizinc, or-tools

I'm trying to solve this problem. Unfortunately I don't have a name for this kind of puzzle so I'm not sure what to search for.  The closest examples I can find are Nonogram and Tomography puzzles.

Puzzle description:
The player is given an empty game board (varying size) that they must fill with n-colors, using clue patterns for the rows and columns. Each clue pattern is the sequence of colors in that row/col but with consecutive duplicates removed.

Here is an example easy small 4x4 grid with 3 colors:

```
rbg,rbr,grb,bgbg       <- (top-to-bottom column constraints)

    _,_,_,_     rgb    <- (row constraints)
    _,_,_,_     brg 
    _,_,_,_     b
    _,_,_,_     grbg
```

Solutions (2):

```
    r,r,g,b
    b,?,r,g     
    b,b,b,b     
    g,r,b,g
```

? Can be either red or blue but not green.

Pattern examples below.
Examples given 6-length sequences to pattern:

```
aaaaaa -> a
aabbcc -> abc
abbbbc -> abc
cabbbc -> cabc
bbbaac -> bac
abbaab -> abab
abcabc -> abcabc
```

Examples given pattern to potential solution sequences:

```
abc -> abc (3 length solution)
abc -> abcc, abbc, aabc (4 length solutions)
abc -> abccc, abbcc, abbbc, aabbc, aaabc (5 length solutions)
```

I've tried to solve it in C# or-tools and MiniZinc but the biggest problem I have is building the constraints.  I can generate the patterns from a sequence (in c# imperative way) but then how to turn that into a constraint?

How I'm thinking about it: generate all potential sequences from each clue pattern.  Then make a constraint for the corresponding row/col that says it must be one of those sequences.

Example from top row in above puzzle: rgb to [4-length sequences] ->  rgbb, rggb, rrgb, and then add a constraint for that row: must equal one of these sequences.

Am I thinking about this right? Any smarter ways to do it?

=====================================

Edit after some progress:

This MiniZinc correctly solves the top row for the pattern abc which has 3 solutions of 4 length:  aabc, abbc, abcc.

```
include "globals.mzn";

array [1..4, 1..4] of var 1..3: colors;

constraint regular(row(colors, 1), 4, 3, 
[|
  % a, b, c
    2,0,0| % accept 'a'
    2,3,0| % accept 'a' or 'b' ?
    0,3,4| % accept 'b' or 'c' ?
    0,0,4| % accept 'c'
|], 1, {4}); 

% Don't care about rest of grid for now.
constraint forall(i,j in 1..4 where i > 1) (row(colors, i)[j] = 1);

solve satisfy;

output [show(colors)];
```

However I'm not sure how to handle larger grids with many patterns other than hardcoding everything like this.  I will experiment a bit more.

Comment: You might get soms inspiration from  my MiniZinc model for generating the regular constraints for the nonogram solver: http://www.hakank.org/minizinc/nonogram_create_automaton2.mzn  It's the predicate make_automaton that do the work. Note: It's not pretty and it's not even small...

Comment: @hakank Wow... that is very dense code!  But I think I understand the general idea is to construct these transition tables.  I also found another of your examples that helped me a lot: [regex](http://hakank.org/or-tools/regex.cs)  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constraints you are talking about seem to be easily represented as regular expressions. For example your `abc` example with varying length can be caught using the regular expression `abc.*`, which requires one `a` then one `b`, and then one `c`, it will accept anything else afterwards.

In MiniZinc these kinds of constraints are expressed using the [`regular` predicate](http://www.minizinc.org/doc-lib/doc-globals-extensional.html). The regular predicate simulates an automaton with accepting states. By providing the allowed state-transitions the model is constraint.

The example expression `abc.*` would be enforced by the following constraint item:

```
% variables considered, nr states, input values
constraint regular(VARS, 4, 1..3, [|
    % a, b, c
    2,0,0| % accept 'a'
    0,3,0| % accept 'b'
    0,0,4| % accept 'c'
    4,4,4| % accept all
|], 1, {4}); % initial state, accepting states
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot.

Comment: The regular predicate isn't quite right but I was able to edit it to something that kinda works.  I will edit my original question to include my progress.

Comment: Currently there is no tool that converts a regular expression or an automata to a `regular` predicate. We would love to offer such an tool, but we're limited by development time.

Answer (score 0):

In Prolog(language), I use `DCG` form to describe such problems. It is extended `BNF` form.
So I suggest finding approach with Extended BNF Form in your environment.

SWI-Prolog example:

```
color_chunk_list(Encoded,Decoded):-
    phrase(chunk_list(Encoded),Decoded),
    chk_continuity(Encoded).

chunk_list([])-->[].
chunk_list([First|Rest])-->colorrow(First),chunk_list(Rest).

colorrow(Color)-->[Color],colorrow(Color).
colorrow(Color)-->[Color].

chk_continuity([First,Second|Rest]):-First \= Second,chk_continuity([Second|Rest]).
chk_continuity([_]).
```

In this program, encodings and decodings are bidirectional.

Tests:

```
?- length(L,4),color_chunk_list([r,g],L).
L = [r, r, r, g] ;
L = [r, r, g, g] ;
L = [r, g, g, g] ;
false.

?- length(L,6),color_chunk_list([a,b,c],L).
L = [a, a, a, a, b, c] ;
L = [a, a, a, b, b, c] ;
L = [a, a, a, b, c, c] ;
L = [a, a, b, b, b, c] ;
L = [a, a, b, b, c, c] ;
L = [a, a, b, c, c, c] ;
L = [a, b, b, b, b, c] ;
L = [a, b, b, b, c, c] ;
L = [a, b, b, c, c, c] ;
L = [a, b, c, c, c, c] ;
false.

?- color_chunk_list(L,[a,a,b,b,c,c]).
L = [a, b, c] ;
false.

?- color_chunk_list(L,[b,r,b,r,r,g,g,b]).
L = [b, r, b, r, g, b] ;
false.
```

In ECLiPSe, which is prolog based CLP system (not IDE one),
above predicate(`color_chunk_list`) can be turned into clp constraint 
with `propia` mechanism and can genarate clp `propagation`.